# How to write test class for Read only Object

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am trying to write test class for below soql, but not understanding how to write. Both objects are read only object.

Can you please help me with test class?

```
global with sharing class LeanDataCustomInterface extnds LeanData.CustomInteerface{
Global Map<id,object>userAvailabilityMap = new Map<id,object>();

 global override Map<ID,Object> userAvailabilityMap(){

list<leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c> leandata = [select LeanData__OwnerId__c from eanData__Round_Robin_setting__c where LeanData__Pool__r.LeanData__Grouping_Name__c != null AND LeanData__User_Owner__c not in (select UsersID from authsession Where Sessiontype = 'UI' AND LastModifiedDat >= :reducedt)];                                                         for(leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c roundrobin:leandata)
{                                            userAvailabilityMap.put(roundrobin.LeanData__OwnerId__c ,'User is Unavailable');
}   
return userAvailabilityMap;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to the SF Stackexchange,

To write a test class for such an object you could try to defer from using stored data in your function.

if your current function looks somewhat similar to this:

```
public static void doSomething(){
   list<leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c> leandata = [select LeanData__OwnerId__c from eanData__Round_Robin_setting__c];
   for(leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c rrs : leandata){
      //do a lot of stuff based on this data
    }
 }
```

try to split this function like so:

```
public static void doSomething(){
   List<leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c> leandata = querySomething();
   processLeanData(leandata);
}

 public static List<leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c> querySomething(){
   List<leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c> leandata = [select LeanData__OwnerId__c from eanData__Round_Robin_setting__c];
   return leandata;
 }

 public static void processLeanData(List<leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c> leandata){
   for(leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c rrs : leandata){
      //do a lot of stuff based on this data
    }
 }
```

next you can call the processLeanData in your test class and leave the query part untested.
if required you could add a if(!Test.isRunningTest()) check for parts you don't want to run if testing.

alternative 3 would be to specify a query result in test cases, you could adjust the code like this:

```
public class MyClass{
   public static List<leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c> tstLeanData {get;set;}

 public static List<leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c> querySomething(){
   if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
      return [select LeanData__OwnerId__c from eanData__Round_Robin_setting__c];
   } else {
      return tstLeanData;
   }
 }
```

test class:

```
@isTest
public void MyClassTest {

   @isTest
   public static void test(){
       List<leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c> tstLeanData = new List<leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c>();
       tstLeanData.add(new leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c(Name='rrsTest'));
       MyClass.tstLeanData = tstLeanData;
       
       Test.startTest();
       MyClass.doSomething();
       Test.stopTest();
     }
}
```

continuing from your code option 3 would look like this:

```
global with sharing class LeanDataCustomInterface extends LeanData.CustomInteerface {
    public static List<leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c> testLeandata;
    global Map<Id, Object> userAvailabilityMap = new Map<Id, Object>();

    global override Map<Id, Object> userAvailabilityMap() {
        List<leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c> leandata = Test.isRunningTest()
            ? testLeandata
            : [
                    SELECT LeanData__OwnerId__c
                    FROM leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c
                    WHERE
                        LeanData__Pool__r.LeanData__Grouping_Name__c != NULL
                        AND LeanData__User_Owner__c NOT IN (
                            SELECT UsersID
                            FROM authsession
                            WHERE Sessiontype = 'UI' AND LastModifiedDat >= :reducedt
                        )
              ];
        for (leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c roundrobin : leandata) {
            userAvailabilityMap.put(roundrobin.LeanData__OwnerId__c, 'User is Unavailable');
        }
        return userAvailabilityMap;
    }
}
```

and test class:

```
public with sharing class LeanDataCustomInterfaceTest {
    @isTest
    public static void test() {
        List<leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c> tstLeanData = new List<leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c>();
        tstLeanData.add(
            new leanData__Round_Robin_setting__c(LeanData__OwnerId__c = UserInfo.getUserId())
        );
        LeanDataCustomInterface.testLeandata = tstLeanData;

        Test.startTest();
        new LeanDataCustomInterface().userAvailabilityMap();
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am Not doing anything on query output just returning  output into the map.

Comment: Than alternative 3 would suffice, if not I would need more context to help you out

Comment: I have added complete code above.